# C# Diff Algorithm for Text

Tags: c#, algorithm, diff

I'm looking for a diff algorithm that will produce results like SO's edit revisions page.  I've more or less just started looking and I'm not opposed to doing it myself but I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

I'll be using C# 4.0.  I'll basically have two strings, and old one and a new one.  I want to know what has changed in the new one by highlighting and strike throughs.

Answer (score 8):

I found that Google has published code for doing diff, match and patch which contains c# classes and test-code. The code is not too hard to use IMHO.

https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch

Well documented here:

https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/API

Answer (score 6):

Its based on [`Longest common subsequence`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm, popularly known as `LCS`.

LCS of old text and new text gives the part that has remain unchanged. So the parts of old text that is not part of LCS is the one that got changed.

From the wiki page above:

> It is a classic computer science problem, the basis of **diff** (a file comparison program that outputs the differences between two files), and has applications in bioinformatics.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [Menees Diff](http://menees.com/Diff.Net.htm) for an example written in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Usually implemented with a [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) algorithm. [This post](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=177) will be of interest.

Comment: Its not longest common **substring** but longest common **subsequence**. A substring is always continuous but a subsequence need not be. The changes made to old text to get new text need not be on consecutive characters.

Comment: Agreed that. You need to classify between longest common subsequence problem vs. longest common substring problem.