# Count Number of Changes Comparing two string in c#

Tags: c#

I want to find out Number of changes comparing two string.
Example:

String 1:

> I hope to do something good from this chance.I think my Test form will
>   help me in ODI. Scoring runs in international cricket, regardless of
>   the format, gives a player confidence.

string 2:

> "I hope to do something good this chance. I think my Testing form will
>   help me in ODI Format. Scoring runs in latest international cricket,
>   regardless of the format, gives a playing confidence."

Expected Output: 5.(ignoring space & newline)

Changes are:

1. from(delete from string 2),
2. Testing(modified in string 2),
3. Format(extra addition in string 2),
4. latest(extra addition in string 2),
5. playing(modified in string 2).

Have any algorithm for count the number of changes?

Comment: Did you do an attempt yourself? If so, please share it with us.

Comment: Why are the extra quotes around the string2 no change? Do you count also different [punctuation characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) like commas, semicolons, brackets, colons, periods or hyphens?

Comment: Generally i'd treat each word as separate line and then use standard diff utility. Would that be enough? For diff algorithms in c# see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764107/c-sharp-diff-algorithm-for-text

Comment: Without knowing the type of changes you are looking for, it is dificult to decide upon a method. For example are you trying to find the number of different words, characters, or would calculating something like the Levenshtein Distance be appropriate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1):

You problem is quite similar to comparing two files.. Difference is In file comparison files are compared by comparing text in a single line. In your case it white space would be a separator instead of Newline.

Typically this is accomplished by finding the Longest Common Subsequence. Here is a related document which explains it: https://nanohub.org/infrastructure/rappture/export/2719/trunk/gui/src/diff.pdf

For finding LCS:

```
 public static int GetLCS(string str1, string str2)
    {
        int[,] table;
        return GetLCSInternal(str1, str2, out table);
    }

    private static int GetLCSInternal(string str1, string str2, out int[,] matrix)
    {
        matrix = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int[,] table = new int[str1.Length + 1, str2.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            table[i, 0] = 0;
        }
        for(int j= 0;j<table.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            table[0,j] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (str1[i-1] == str2[j-1])
                    table[i, j] = table[i - 1, j - 1] + 1;
                else
                {
                    if (table[i, j - 1] > table[i - 1, j])
                        table[i, j] = table[i, j - 1];
                    else
                        table[i, j] = table[i - 1, j];
                }
            }
        }

        matrix = table;
        return table[str1.Length, str2.Length];
    }
```

//Reading Out All LCS sorted in lexicographic order

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
 using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LambdaPractice
{
class Program
{


    static int[,] c;

   static int max(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }

   static int LCS(string s1, string s2)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= s1.Length; i++)
            c[i,0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s2.Length; i++)
            c[0, i] = 0;

        for (int i=1;i<=s1.Length;i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= s2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (s1[i-1] == s2[j-1])
                    c[i, j] = c[i - 1, j - 1] + 1;
                else
                {
                    c[i, j] = max(c[i - 1, j], c[i, j - 1]);

                }

            }

        return c[s1.Length, s2.Length]; 

    }
```

/*      Prints one LCS
       static string BackTrack(string s1, string s2, int i, int j)
        {

```
        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            return "";
        if (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1])
            return BackTrack(s1, s2, i - 1, j - 1) + s1[i - 1];
        else if (c[i - 1, j] > c[i, j - 1])
            return BackTrack(s1, s2, i - 1, j);
        else
            return BackTrack(s1, s2, i, j - 1);

    }*/

   static SortedSet<string> backtrack(string s1, string s2, int i, int j)
   {
       if (i == 0 || j == 0)
           return new SortedSet<string>(){""} ;
       else if (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1])
       {
           SortedSet<string> temp = new SortedSet<string>();
           SortedSet<string> holder = backtrack(s1, s2, i - 1, j - 1);
           if (holder.Count == 0)
           {
              temp.Add(s1[i - 1]);
           }
           foreach (string str in holder)

                temp.Add(str + s1[i - 1]);


           return temp;
       }
       else
       {
           SortedSet<string> Result = new SortedSet<string>() ;
           if (c[i - 1, j] >= c[i, j - 1])
           {
               SortedSet<string> holder = backtrack(s1, s2, i - 1, j);

               foreach (string s in holder)
                   Result.Add(s);
           }

           if (c[i, j - 1] >= c[i - 1, j])
           {
               SortedSet<string> holder = backtrack(s1, s2, i, j - 1);

               foreach (string s in holder)
                   Result.Add(s);
           }


           return Result;
       }

   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string s1, s2;
            s1 = Console.ReadLine();
            s2 = Console.ReadLine();
            c = new int[s1.Length+1, s2.Length+1];
            LCS(s1, s2);
            // Console.WriteLine(BackTrack(s1, s2, s1.Length, s2.Length));
            //  Console.WriteLine(s1.Length);
            SortedSet<string> st = backtrack(s1, s2, s1.Length, s2.Length);

            foreach (string str in st)
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            GC.Collect();

       Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Links can be broken in the future. Please copy-paste the specific answer or code-part to this answer. Use the link only as a reference.

Comment: well that's many pages long document.

Comment: You could try to summarize it. Try to catch the essence of the article. Name the various methods / techniques and how they work together. Names of techniques and methods can be googled after the link is broken.

Comment: That I have already mentioned. Search for "finding the Longest Common Subsequence in c sharp"

Comment: I can't understand your code.can you help me to provide organize step by step code. @MartinMulder

Answer (score 0):

could you check this [might be useful somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343874/compare-two-strings-and-get-the-difference), I would say you'll use a lot of control statements (if/else or switch) for result sets.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear. Care to expand your answer?

Comment: Links can be broken in the future. Please copy-paste the specific answer or code-part to this answer. Use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it relatively easy, if you you consider a string as `modified` if it is starting with another string:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = "I hope to do something good from this chance.I think my Test form will help me in ODI.Scoring runs in international cricket, regardless of the format, gives a player confidence.";

    var b = "I hope to do something good this chance. I think my Testing form will help me in ODI Format. Scoring runs in latest international cricket, regardless of the format, gives a playing confidence.";

    var d = new Difference(a,b);

    Console.WriteLine("Number of differences: {0}", d.Count);

    foreach (var diff in d.Differences)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Different: {0}", diff);
    }
}

class Difference
{
    string a;
    string b;

    List<string> notInA;
    List<string> notInB;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return notInA.Count + notInB.Count; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Differences
    {
        get { return notInA.Concat(notInB); }
    }

    public Difference(string a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

        var itemsA = Split(a);
        var itemsB = Split(b);

        var changedPairs =
            from x in itemsA
            from y in itemsB
            where (x.StartsWith(y) || y.StartsWith(x)) && y != x
            select new { x, y };

        var softChanged = changedPairs.SelectMany(p => new[] {p.x, p.y}).Distinct().ToList();

        notInA = itemsA.Except(itemsB).Except(softChanged).ToList();
        notInB = itemsB.Except(itemsA).Except(softChanged).ToList();
    }

    IEnumerable<string> Split(string x)
    {
        return x.Split(new[] { " ", ".", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number of differences: 5
Different: from
Different: player
Different: Format
Different: latest
Different: playing
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.but it's not working.