# Getting Exact File Changes C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I wrote a program in c#, the program is reading a file, and when something in the file changes, the method OnFileChanged starts. And that works. **But now I want to get the exact new lines, which are in my file. So that i have maybe a string where the new lines are in.** In the file can only come new lines.

This is my FileSystemWatcher, that works:

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  fileWatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
  fileWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath.Split(backslashSeperator).Last());
  fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileChanged);
  fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and this is my OnFileChanged method:

```
 public static void OnFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {

}
```

now I want to have maybe a string with the exact line changes in my file.

Answer (score 1):

`FileSystemWatcher` API doesn't provide the old version of the file.

You need to store the last state of the file somewhere, and then the next time it changes, you need to follow a [Text Difference Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764107/c-sharp-diff-algorithm-for-text) to get the difference between the 2 sets.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is not directly possible. Your program is notified of file being changed by the event from the file system. File system does not check for specific lines which has been changed. After all: the changed file could be a binary file, image, zip file, etc.

You will have to implement such logic yourself. Create a copy of the file somewhere, and then when you receive the `Change` event, you compare the backup copy with the actuall file and calculate changes.

Or maybe you use some diff tool, like the one built in `git`, but I have no idea how to do that :)